# Use the Eloquent with in a 1 to 1 relationship, good or bad practice?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In relationship 1 -> 1.

(Whereas a person may have only one address)

Assuming I need to get all the people active in the system:

```
Person::where ('status', 'A') -> get ();
```

However, I need to get at least one address from each active person in the system, which in the end turns out to be a 1 to 1 relationship, but I will not get a single user, since, in 1 to 1, you would need to give a Fist () or find ().

One way to resolve would be:

```
Person::where ('status', 'A') -> with ('address') -> get ();
```

But in this example, where I search for all users, and I need to retrieve the address together (**as if it were an inner join**), the `with` method ends up being a good or bad practice?

Comment: use https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ or use english to communicate here

Comment: Excuse me. I changed to english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well of course it is always good to use eager loading (with() is used for eager loading).
Also if you just need to get all users that have at least an address. Then you might need to use the has() function.

```
User::has('yourRelationName')->get()
```

Comment: even in a one-to-one relationship?

Comment: yeah no problem with it.

Comment: usually with() is used when you need to create an API. But for simple web application you can use lazy loading as well

Answer (score 1):

I think it all depends on what we can agree a best practice is. I've learnt so far that best practices are not always synonim of convenience. And we have a choice to make due with what we've got or refactor/migrate it when possible.

It seems by your example that you are looking for a convenient way to gather certain information and for that we can use [Laravel Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes) or some other techniques such as [repositories](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html).

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function scopeWithAddress($query)
    {
        return $query->with('address');
    }
    public function scopeWithRoleAdmin($query)
    {
        return $query->withAddress()->where('role', 'admin');
    }
}
```

And use it

```php
$users = User::withRoleAdmin()->get();
```